# Как подключиться к mongoDB с помощью shell?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, shell

mongo "mongodb://Имя-хоста:27017/test?replicaSet=Имя" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username мой-юзернэйм --password Мой_Пароль

Что не так с запросом?

Comment: какую ошибку выбрасывает?

Comment: connecting to: mongodb://Username:Password@Hostname:27017/city?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0
2018-07-04T13:15:10.755+0300 Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 231

2018-07-04T13:15:10.757+0300 Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:231 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed

Comment: А доступ для Вашего IP открыт на сервере?

Comment: с помощью ping проверил - есть

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15739 - вот тут пишут, что  `mongodb://` должно быть удалено из URI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929040/javascript-execution-failed-connected-to-mongohq-shell - здесь в ответе на похожий вопрос тоже обходятся без `mongodb://`